# Is it bad to mount WSL paths into a container running under Docker for Windows?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, docker-for-windows, docker

I'm aware that it's **not a good idea to access WSL Linux files** (located in `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc\LocalState\rootfs\`) **directly from Windows**, but does that recommendation also apply to mounting a WSL path as a volume in a container running under Docker for Windows?

For example, if I first do this on Windows:

```
mklink /j %USERPROFILE%\wsl %LOCALAPPDATA%\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc\LocalState\rootfs
```

Then do this in WSL with Docker already configured:

```
$ docker run --rm -v /c/Users/$USER/wsl/home/$USER/myapp:/myapp -ti ubuntu:18.04 bash
```

*The above assumes the requisite "`root=/`" in "/etc/wsl.conf" and that the user has the same name in both environments.*

I can see my files inside the container under "`/myapp`" just fine, but I'm not sure **whether it's safe to write to that path**. If both WSL and the container are running Ubuntu, is it any safer?

I really prefer to work full-time from WSL with my home directory containing the familiar Linux dot files.

And just for kicks, what if in WSL "`$HOME/myapp`" is a symlink to "`/c/myapp`"? Yes, I should then just use `-v /c/myapp:/myapp` for simplicity, but is traversing through the rootfs paths really bad?

Answer (score 0):

Accessing the file paths through Docker on Windows still uses Windows symantecs to access the files, therefore you will bork your WSL distro instance. However the newest Windows Insider includes a Plan9 server embedded into the proprietary /init that allows access of Linux files from Windows via network share essentially. See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2019/02/15/whats-new-for-wsl-in-windows-10-version-1903/

An alternative would be to use ssh/scp from win-32 ssh on the same Windows host (or another) or from a Linux host.